# Use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to find the inverse of this $3$-by-$3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0\\
1&3&0\\
-3&5&3
\end{pmatrix}.$

I can find the characteristic polynomial $C_a(A)= -A^3 + 8A^2-21A+18$.

How to continue from here to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to find the inverse matrix, $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Here are a couple of top hits from searching for `cayley hamilton inverse`: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780160/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744378/inverse-of-a-matrix-is-expressable-as-a-polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we know $p(A) = 0$, you can multiply by $A^{-1}$ both sides to have:

$$ -A^2 + 8 A - 21 \, I+ 18 A^{-1} = 0,$$

can you solve for $A^{-1}$?

**Spoiler**:

> The answer is given by $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{18} \left( 21 I - 8 A + A^2   \right) =\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ \frac{7}{9} & -\frac{5}{9} & \frac{1}{3}\end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

${Hint:}$

If $-A^3+8A^2-21A+18I=0$, then $A(-A^2+8A-21I)=-18I$.

Comment: An advantage of this approach, rather than multiplying by $A^{-1}$, is that one needs not know that $A^{-1}$ exists a priori.

Comment: In **this particular case**, it's rather simple to show that $|A| \neq 0$, isn't it?

Comment: @Dmoreno: It sure is.