# Show that there exist $a_1,\ldots, a_{2n-1}$ such that $ a_{2n-1}J^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_1 J=I_n,$ where $J$ is a Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, jordan-normal-form

Let $J\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a Jordan normal form and assume that ${\rm tr~}J<2n$. Prove or disprove that there exist $a_1,\ldots, a_{2n-1}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
a_{2n-1}J^{2n-1}+a_{2n-2}J^{2n-2}+\cdots+a_1 J=I_n.
\end{equation}

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. For example, any Jordan matrix with zeros on the diagonal satisfies the condition, but no such coefficients exist.

Comment: Thanks. What if $J$ has no zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Then this is possible, even without the condition on the trace

Comment: @JamesVestal See [this post, for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780160/81360)

Comment: Did you notice that J is $n$ by $n$ but  we have $J^{2n-1}$ present?

Comment: @JamesVestal Yes, and I don't see how that makes a difference. We can simply take $a_{n+1} = a_{n+2} = \cdots = a_{2n - 1} = 0$, and apply the process described in the answers to the post to find the remaining coefficients.